# Scroll view not wrapping around its content

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

I got such problem: i have a MapView and a ListView below it. Map size is fixed. But I need to scroll my views together. I, somehow, handled problems with non-scrolling map and one-itemed-list, but another one showed up - in a ScrollView there are lots of free space below ListView and I can't get rid of it. I thought that setting for the list to "wrap_content" would help, but it did not.
What to do?
Here is my layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <com.package.MyMapView
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="100dp"
                     android:clickable="true"
                     android:apiKey="key"
                     android:id="@+id/map"
                     android:layout_gravity="top"/>
        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/channelsList" >

        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its always not a good idea to wrap **ListView** inside **ScrollView**, because both are scrollable views.

Comment: I know. There are plenty of questions with answers like this, but I do not ask if it is a good idea, I just have a goal which I have to achieve. And the goal is: i need one "page" with map and list, which should be scrollable together.

Comment: So if you scroll the map, the list also gets scroll?

Comment: nope. there are two views in a scrollview. i need to scroll the map to look through it. but when i scroll the list down i need map to go off the screen as list scrolls.

Comment: then try adding Map as header view of ListView

Answer (score 1):

Can you try replacing these lines:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
```

with these lines:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
```

Comment: fill_parent was replaced by match_parent. It means the same but the later one should be used.

Answer (score 1):

**Do not insert any ListViews in a ScrollView,** that will not satisfy your requirement in any case. Try to make the MapView to be added as a header to your ListView to make it scroll along with your list.

To implement the mapView as a header, in your java code, simply include `addHeaderView(<your_map_view>)` to your listView component. This should necessarily be called before `setAdapter()` is called.

Comment: I tried, but I couldn't add a map as a header. By now I got wotking map and a list, he problem is: below my list there are plenty of empty space. which (as i suppose) should not be there